# My iPhone app ran fine in simulator but crashed on device (iPod touch 3.1.2) test, I got the following errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

I was running myapp on an iPod touch and I noticed it missed some libraries. Is that the reason?

```
[Session started at 2010-03-19 15:57:04 +0800.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1128) (Fri Dec 18 10:08:53 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys007
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-237-78
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11779]
[Switching to thread 11779]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb) continue
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
2010-03-19 15:57:18.892 myapp[2338:207] MS:Notice: Installing: com.yourcompany.myapp [myapp] (478.52)
2010-03-19 15:57:19.145 myapp[2338:207] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
MS:Warning: message not found [myappAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]
MS:Warning: message not found [myappAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]
2010-03-19 15:57:19.550 myapp[2338:207] in FirstViewController
2010-03-19 15:57:20.344 myapp[2338:207] in load table view
2010-03-19 15:57:20.478 myapp[2338:207] in loading splash view
2010-03-19 15:57:22.793 myapp[2338:207] in set interface
Program received signal:  “0”.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signal 0 is usually (but not always) related to the device running out of memory. In my own testing, I have seen an app quit with signal 0 after loading large images or poor memory management.

Rebooting the device may help, but as it seems you're using a jailbroken iPhone/iPod, there could be any number of things wrong.

I would hazard a guess that all the background apps are taking up so much memory that your app has none left to play with. The effect is magnified when hooking in the debugger, as that requires extra memory to run too.

My suggestion is to not use a jailbroken iPhone/iPod. But that's entirely your call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to find another test device :)

Answer (score 2):

Those messages are from using jail broke phones. They are most likely unrelated to your error. Without more information, we will not be able to help you track down the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using some libraries. Make shore that you include them in the correct way.

If it isn't the cause, provide more information.